# What is a Cib? (objective-j related? I'm not sure)

Tags: objective-j

I was looking at some Cappuccino code (trying learn a little bit of it) and saw something called a Cib. 
http://github.com/Calvin4/simple-cappuccino-sinatra-app/blob/master/public/AppController.j
Look at line 27.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cib is most likely the Cappuccino version of a Nib/Xib, which is a file that describes the controls and layout of a page (i.e. if this was WPF/Silverlight it'd be a XAML page)

Comment: Is it possible to relate this to something a Windows+Rails developer would understand?

Comment: Ummm, I guess it'd be like a View.

Comment: I'd like to add that a cib can contain just about anything, not just view elements. For example, you can instantiate any arbitrary object (model, view, controller, you name it) in there.